# Can we have a feature to turn off display of "medals"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Many of use comes here to share knowledge, not to glimmer with "goldies". Some of us doesn't care for them at all, but some of us has more emotional point of view and are tired with seeing own badges and points below each post.

Can we / should we have a feature, that will allow user to disable displaying of badges and points and display nothing or for example number of questions and answers instead?

I have the feeling, that there are many people here, who value those asking and answering good quality stuff than those having a lot of "goldies" from for example review work, madness of visiting site each of 100 following days and sharing link among thousands of other kind of maniac.

This feature request / question covers only disabling displaying of **own** points and badges and only under posts. User profile and other users info below posts should remain unchanged.

Comment: Meh. This seems like a lot of effort for very little gain. It seems that if the badges bother you so much you should craft up some custom CSS that will hide them (from you).

Comment: But wait - I love chemistry. That's why I visit Chem.SE. That doesn't mean I'm crazy! :(

Answer (score 2):

No. Badges and reputation are one metric to determine how 'valid' a post is and how the user is trusted in the community.

Of course, a 1-rep user can give a very good answer, but that same answer from someone with 100K rep shows the user has a record of good answers, making it even more trustworthy.

Also, reputation and badges are a part of the gamification of the site. Of course, yours could be hidden, but that would go against this.

I wonder how many users would want to use this feature. If not that much, that would make it another reason why this should be a not-that-important feature request.

Comment: I must totally disagree with you. For me personally, badges and reputation are metrics of **user's history and actions on site** and has nothing to do with quality of posts. Assuming, that someone can (will always) give a good answer or ask a good question only because he/she has a great 'score' is very wrong. On contrary, people with high rank tend to show less self-criticism, falls into routine and seems to be ignoring certain problems, 'beginners' has. This behavior is observed across entire Internet, across its entire history and on nearly every forum or among nearly every community.

Comment: But, this is, of course, completely off-topic of this question. I'm only trying to show you, that claiming, that showing badges and score is essential, because it has something to do with quality of posts or entire site -- is wrong.

Comment: Someones continued contribution to the site *should* pay off in reputation, so it is kind-of a metric.

Comment: Of course! But, again, has nothing to do with quality of question or answer. And you stated, that we show badges and score below each post, because it suggests quality of that post. At least, this is how I understand your answer.